# Periodic blinking light on Hunter ceiling fan

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

Our 5 blade Hunter fan is about 5 years old. It did not come with a remote so I recently purchased an after market remote which is a Patriot Lighting Universal 3 Speed Remote Control # D8B53506. Ever since this remote was installed we noticed the fan lights will blink periodically like maybe 5-7 times per hour. I've checked wiring connections and changed bulbs from LED to conventional which has appeared to improve the blinking from 5-7 times to maybe 3-4 times per hour. I've been reading and one individual said to remove the voltage protector so wondering what your thoughts were about doing that? Should I give this a try?

Comment: did you also start using AC around that time? I know it turning on makes some of my LED bulbs "blink".

Comment: The device that others have suggested you change is the current regulator, they do go bad but I would expect incandescent lamps to have more of an issue, Dan may be on the right path if your AC compressor is kicking in and causing the line voltage to droop the remote module may be glitching with the turn on droop or turn off spike.

Comment: The AC compressor could certainly be a factor however, this was happening long before we ever started running the AC.